# How do I move an object so it's aligned to another object's face's rotation?

Tags: objects, transforms, faces

I'd like to move an object so it's aligned to another object's face's rotation, but have no idea how.
Here is a picture of the objects.
[image]
I am wanting the top object's rotation to match the rotation of the face highlighted of the bottom object. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If these are 2 separate meshes within the same object, separate them in 2 different objects, you'll join them back later.

Enable the *Snap* tool with these options: *Face/Closest/Align Rotation to Target/Move*:

[image]

Then move your object:

[image]